# how to randomize the order of buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, button

I've read about collections to randomize the order of an object. With that, I'd like to try to randomize my buttons in my android application.

Here a chunk of code:

```
 Button[] bObject = new Button[6];
 private void getCorrectObject() {
    // TODO getCorrectObject

    List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        objects.add(0);
        objects.add(1);
        objects.add(2);
        objects.add(3);
        objects.add(4);

    // Shuffle the collection
    Collections.shuffle(objects);

    bObject[objects]; // I'm having trouble implementing the shuffle logic here.


}
```

SO any helpful response is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need any 'more' shuffle logic, after `Collections.shuffle()` the list is shuffled. If you're experiencing an error, the shuffle isn't the root of your problem.

Comment: So should we run that code for you, or what exactly is your question?

Comment: @ClassStacker I'm having trouble implementing the shuffle logic in my UI..

Comment: as you can't solve this within the layout-file, i would propose to just shuffle your list and initialize first object to findViewById(R.id.button1) and so on.

Comment: @bofredo can you show me how to do that? Thanks

Comment: *update* got it for a fixed number of buttons. trying to solve this dynamically now

Comment: @bofredo okay thanks to you. I'm solving this as well.

Comment: update: hey i got it solved with some help from stackoverflow

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29101/discussion-between-neknek-mouh-and-bofredo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it solved manually and then tried to get it solved dynamically aswell. got a nice idea that you can do it with a second arraylist.

```
List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            objects.add(0);
            objects.add(1);
            objects.add(2);
            objects.add(3);
            objects.add(4);

        // Shuffle the collection
    Collections.shuffle(objects);

    List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button0));
    buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1));
    buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2));
    buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button3));
    buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button4));

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        buttons.get(i).setText(objects.get(i).toString());
    }
```

does this help you?

**EDIT:**
yes let us solve this in chat. im also curious how this can be done!

Comment: Hello I tried the code above but I wonder why the buttons' positions aren't changed?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is randomly change the position of the button like button1 is placed on the left corner, button2 is placed on the right side, button3 is placed on top and button4 is placed at the bottom. I want to randly change their position like button 4 to be placed on the left corner, etc...

Comment: i thought you just wanted to have 5 buttons on a fixed position and shuffle them.  1,2,3,4,5 --> 3,1,5,4,2

Comment: to place them randomnly on your ui is above my level. think that it will be a tough job to achieve it

Comment: Because my buttons have drawables that's why I want them to be placed randomly

Comment: do you have any alternative ways to achieve this?

Comment: well you can try using LayoutParams and feed the X and Y of each button with Random-values. but this will look horrible :)

Comment: or you build like 10 different layout-xmls and choose one by random everytime you want to shuffle :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29111/discussion-between-neknek-mouh-and-bofredo)

Answer (score 0):

first

```
Button[] bObject=new Button[6];
```

second:

```
for(int i=0;i<objects.size;i++)
   bObject[i]=objects.get(i);
```

or:

```
for(Object obj : objects)
 bObject[i]=obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Shuffling the elements in the `bObject` array.

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(bObject));
```

Comment: type mismatch: cannot convert from integer to button in this line: objects.get(random);

Comment: @neknekmouh - check my update! I has erred while reading your question initially!

Comment: Hi I tried using the code provided but it's still not randomizing the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem (shuffle buttons) and i come up with an easy solution
I just used an array of integer numbers of buttons ids and simple shufle. In my case was that enough. It's simple and u get the same result.

```
Integer[] a =  { 0x7f090049, 0x7f09004b, 0x7f09004c, 0x7f090048};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(a));

button1 = (Button)findViewById(a[0]);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(a[1]);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(a[2]);
button4 = (Button)findViewById(a[3]);
```

I hope this will help. 
Regards !!
(srry for my broken english)