# randomise ImageViews to make the game random

Tags: java, android

i have created a pairs game it all works but as you can see its made in 1 set way ive put 4 buttons in the code as theres 24 buttons in total keeping it short i want to know if theres a way of randomising the game eg is it possible to randomise the button names the pic1 pic2 pic3 pic4 or the ids imageview1 2 3 4 ive done lots of searching so not a rush question please be patient if i dont get it and please use my code to show me so i know where im at snipets of code dont work for me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {        
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final ImageView pic1 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);      
final ImageView pic2 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);           
final ImageView pic3 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
final ImageView pic4 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView4); 

      pic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
    public void onClick(View v) {             
     pic1.setTag("beck");    
 if (pic1.getTag()==("beck"))  {pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.becks);}  

 if (pic2.getTag()==("beck")){                  
     pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

 if (pic3.getTag()==("rob") || pic4.getTag()==("rob")) {
     pic1.setTag  ("boot");pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic2.setTag  ("boot");pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic3.setTag ("boot");pic3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
     pic4.setTag ("boot");pic4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); }       
     }});   

        pic2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                         
    public void onClick(View v) {  
        pic2.setTag ("beck");

    if (pic2.getTag()==("beck")){pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.becks);} 

    if (pic1.getTag()==("beck"))   {            
        pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }

    if (pic3.getTag()==("rob") || pic4.getTag()==("rob")) {
        pic1.setTag  ("boot");pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic2.setTag ("boot");pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic3.setTag ("boot");pic3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic4.setTag ("boot");pic4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); }
        }});        

        pic3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
    public void onClick(View v) {          
        pic3.setTag("rob"); 
    if (pic3.getTag()==("rob")){pic3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.robs);}

    if (pic4.getTag()==("rob")){    
        pic3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pic4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }

    if (pic1.getTag()==("beck") || pic2.getTag()==("beck")) {
        pic1.setTag ("boot");pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic2.setTag ("boot");pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic3.setTag ("boot");pic3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic4.setTag ("boot");pic4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); }
        }});      

        pic4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                         
     public void onClick(View v) {  
        pic4.setTag ("rob");        

    if (pic4.getTag()==("rob")){pic4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.robs);}    

    if (pic3.getTag()==("rob")){        
         pic3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         pic4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }    

    if (pic1.getTag()==("beck") || pic2.getTag()==("beck")) {
        pic1.setTag ("boot");pic1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic2.setTag ("boot");pic2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic3.setTag ("boot");pic3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots);
        pic4.setTag ("boot");pic4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jordboots); }
        }});             
        }}
```

is this any closer to solveing my question if so how do i assign the images to the backgrounds of the imageviews

```
ArrayList<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array(R.drawable.becks);
array(R.drawable.jordboots);
array(R.drawable.becks);
array(R.drawable.robs);
array(R.drawable.robs);
Collections.shuffle(objects);
```

Comment: if (pic1.getTag()==("beck")) seems incrorrect shold it be if (String.valueOf(pic1.getTag())).equals("beck")) ? I mean all your if statements seem incorrent. If your only problem is this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me use the list to hold the id info then add the shuffle method and name your buttons as usual

```
List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
objects.add(R.id.imageView1);  
objects.add(R.id.imageView2);       
objects.add(R.id.imageView3); 
objects.add(R.id.imageView4);
// Shuffle the collection
Collections.shuffle(objects); 

ImageView pic1 = (ImageView ) findViewById(objects.get(0));        
ImageView pic2 = (ImageView ) findViewById(objects.get(1));        
ImageView pic3 = (ImageView ) findViewById(objects.get(2));
ImageView pic4 = (ImageView ) findViewById(objects.get(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of see what you're doing here but I think that your approach is extremely weird.

You should have a data structure that backs your model. Your data model should represent every possible Pair (or even a single item). That object must have a unique identifier, and it must also have a type (beck, boot, etc.). There should be a way to reference the correct image for each type (I.e.: beck uses R.drawable.beck).

Then you should have a way to generate the "random" data. I.e.: your data structure (an array) contains all the tiles or "imageviews data".

From there it should be much easier.

Rethink your problem again. It's not difficult, but I think your approach is making it super complicated.

Comment: i,m very new to tags strings etc most of my logic is based on ints  at moment  i,m only learning of youtube etc no prof help at all a couple of examples online with string and a shuffle method i want to move away from ints because of limited uses for them but cant get more info online. lots of words i will get to know but don,t yet a line of code to show me the way would be appreciated as i don,t get your explanation to good (data structure)??  i thought the tags were the unique id or the button names pic1 etc could be randomised and remember i am a beginner be nice and patient :-)

Comment: Are you making a Pairs game where you see a Board with Tiles, and so you click one Tile and it flips (revealing what's the image) and then you click another one and it also flips. If they are the same, both remain flipped, or else they hide again?

Comment: yes pretty much i am but after second image reveals they dissapear from the screen nothing replaces them

Comment: pic1.setTag(R.drawable.becks); does not work at all has to have "" also whats difference between pic1.setTag("becks") and above no difference except longer name how does this help to randomise ???

Comment: Michael, have you taken a look at LibGDX? (It may take a few days to understand it, but this would be extremely easier using a dedicated gaming framework/engine). Each card would be an Actor in your scene and you could perform "actions" in those actors. Etc. Better performance (OpenGL!) and easier to deal with ;)

Comment: complicated for me im on a mac also on ios 6 so cant update things would rather write the roar code so close i did 1 earlier it worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276254/how-to-randomize-the-order-of-buttons-in-android but when i ran no images but there was o1234 on the buttons so it worked i need  that array with images as above example or a button id version for future im so close if i can turn the linked example into image or button array also on the linked example i couldnt work out how to add the  click listener im close i know it been juggling the code round allday i am trying

Comment: Being on Mac has nothing to do with LibGDX, since this is an Android question, neither does iOS 6 :) LibGDX is a Java Library that you can include in your Android project. But ruling LiBGDX, I'll take a deeper look at your code later when I'm off work.

Comment: I appreciate that I have the full working game its just not randomised. I did look at the LibGDX site the setup video for mac looked a bit scary ill take a closer look later. Once i get the game randomised i,m hopeing to learn to put the methods in another class and just call on them. If I could learn that array or list method i can apply that to my other  4 games there all working but all in a set way. Again thanks for patience

Comment: What do you want to randomize now?

Comment: What i would most like is to Randomise the Buttonid eg button0 button1 etc. Then i can just use my working games as they all work on the bases of button pressing so that would be ideal. I have adapted the above link with the above arraylist and it works. But in the above link i put earlier the button list is an add button list and i dont know how to add the Clicklistener to the array with buttons that all have same name. When i adapted it for my buttons as in Button pic1 = (Button ) findViewById(R.id.button0); the button list this way crashes.

Comment: Glad to hear you seem to have solved your problem. I've been quite busy and unable to help you.